# How to use Kernel Density Estimation for Prediction?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, smoothing, kernel-smoothing

I would like to apply KDE to inventory replenishment, but I am not sure how to use the analysis to predict future sales based on past sales. Given a set of data and having applied KDE to it (probably using a Gaussian distribution), how do I make a prediction about the future?

Thanks for any help! Please let me know if I can clarify - I'm only starting to pick up the language for talking about KDE ... I'm glad to do reading on my own - pointers to any resources would be welcome.

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about your problem? Why exactly do you want to use KDE? I happen to be rather active in the area of forecasting & replenishment, and I have never seen anyone use KDE. As onestop below notes, at first glance one would much rather use some kind of time series analysis method.

Comment: Another question: how does a Gaussian *distribution* enter into KDE? Are you sure you are not looking at a Gaussian *kernel*?

Comment: Mostly because I read KDE generalizes histograms, and our current program essentially buckets sales and calculates an average, which seemed like it was related to me.  

I probably meant Gaussian kernel ... apologies, I'm not up on the terminology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use conditional kernel density estimation to obtain the density of sales at time $t+h$ conditional on the values of sales at times $t, t-1, t-2, \dots$ This gives you a density forecast rather than a point forecast. The problem is that the conditioning is difficult in a density setting when the number of conditioning variables is more than 2. See [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1390887) for a discussion of the basic idea.

An alternative procedure that imposes more assumptions (but allows more conditioning variables) is to fit an additive autoregression such as described in [Chen and Tsay (1993)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2290787) and then use kde on the residuals to obtain the forecast densities.

However, I suspect that both of these are more complicated than what you really want. I suggest you read a textbook on demand forecasting such as [Levenbach and Cleary (2006)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534262686).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I actually requested your book from my local university. :)

Answer (score 5):

I would have thought that KDE bear little if any relationship to predicting future sales based on past sales. Sounds more like [time series analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) to me, though that's really not my area.

Comment: I second this answer... and this really *is* my area (or at least I tell myself it is).

Comment: I've retagged the Q to add 'time-series'. Turns out there's a max of 5 tags, so i took out 'pdf'.

Comment: I suspect you are right. Maybe I should recast my question "How do I know I have a problem where KDE can help"?